# Entity metadata for Company#companyTypesLinks was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object

Tags: typescript, typeorm

i have an issue with my entities relation, i have try everything but still got same issue
here is my scripts:

Company.entity.ts

```
export class Company extends AppBaseEntity {
  @Column('text', { name: 'nom', nullable: true })
  nom: string;
  @Column('varchar', { name: 'type_entite', length: 255, nullable: true })
  typeEntite?: CompanyEntityType;
  @Column('text', { name: 'note', nullable: true })
  note: string;

  @Column('varchar', { name: 'color', length: 15, nullable: true })
  color?: string;

  @Column('text', { name: 'textMailInvoices', nullable: true })
  textMailInvoices?: string;
  @Column('varchar', { name: 'subjectMailInvoices', length: 255, nullable: true })
  subjectMailInvoices?: string;
  @Column('tinyint', { name: 'archived', nullable: false, default: 0 })
  archived: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => CompanyTypesLinks, companyTypesLink => companyTypesLink.company, { cascade: true, onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  public companyTypesLinks?: CompanyTypesLinks[];
```

and company-type-link.entity.ts

```
export class CompanyTypesLinks extends AppBaseEntity {
    @Column('varchar', { name: 'typesId', length: 36, nullable: true })
    typesId: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => Company, company => company.companyTypesLinks, { cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'companyId' })
    public company?: Company;

    @Column('varchar', { name: 'companyId', length: 36, nullable: true })
    companyId: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => CompanyTypes, companyTypes => companyTypes.companyTypesLinks)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'typesId' })
    companyType?: CompanyTypes;
```

AppBaseEntity contains id

Answer (score 0):

I ve solved it by renaming my company-type-link file, in fact the file was :

company-type-link.ts instead of

company-type-link.entity.ts

the entity term was missing